# In Android, how do I scale a layout vertically using weight with known proportions?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-linearlayout

I have an existing image that is 320x480 and is set to the background attribute of a LinearLayout.  I understand that for different devices, this is going to stretch vertically/horizontally unevenly, but that's acceptable.

The image is divided into 3 parts, a header, a grid for buttons, and a footer.  The header is 184 pixels, the grid is 240 pixels, and the footer is 56 pixels.

If I set the parent LinearLayout's weightSum attribute to 480, then the layout_weight attributes for each section to it's appropriate pixel amount, the layouts are horribly unaligned.

All of the sections have "fill_parent" as the width and "0dp" as the height, and there are no padding or margin properties on any of the 3 children of the top level LinearLayout.

Ideally, the width will always stretch to the entirety of the screen, and the height will scale proportionally so that the buttons will line up with the grid in the background.

I cannot re-slice the background image (otherwise I would) into multiple pieces.

Comment: Is your linearlayout set to fill_parent for the height?

Comment: The top-level LinearLayout is "fill_parent" for height and width.  Each child is "fill_parent" for the width, "0dp" for the height, and the appropriate value as per above for the weight.  The top-level LinearLayout has weightSum="480".

Comment: Is this an image you "control" ? Is it PNG ? If so, you can simply use a Nine-patch to make your life simpler

Comment: The two problems are that it isn't doing the correct proportion, and it shifts around on different screen sizes (i.e. it might be 5% off on one screen size/density but like 20% off on another)

Comment: No - I cannot modify the image (it's auto-generated)

Comment: Are you setting the images as source images in an ImageView or background of a View?  Backgrounds stretch and scale according to the size of the view.  ImageView will only do that if you set `scaleType` to `FITXY`.  Other options are `centerCrop` which will fill the `ImageView` completely and crop out the excess if it's too large.  It will do nothing if the image is too small.

Comment: I really like Philippe Girolami's answer: Use a 9-patch.  It will stretch proportionally wherever there are black pixels on the top and left side.

Comment: There is only one image - it is the `background` of a LinearLayout

Comment: The problem is not the image stretching - it actually stretches fine.  I just want the 3 child views to have height as a certain percentage of the total height of the parent view (i.e. 184/480, 240/480, and 56/480)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem: The previewer in IntelliJ (and presumably Eclipse) doesn't show the same thing that a real device will.  Turns out that my strategy worked fine all along - the previewer just doesn't do a great job with this particular strategy.